# Obtaining *args and **kwargs from passed func

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, args, keyword-argument

In the below code, how would I obtain *args and **kwargs in function f without the need for the wrapper function?

```
def f(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

@f
def write(text):
    print(text)

# write = a(write)

write('dog')
```

Failed attempt 1:

```
def f(func):
    a=func(*args)
    k=func(**kwargs)
```

which causes error:

```
NameError: global name 'args' is not defined
```

Failed attempt 2:

```
def f(func(*args,**kwargs)):
    a=func(*args)
    k=func(**kwargs)
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Understand how decorators work by understanding how *args and **kwargs are passed through f to wrapper.  I felt if I could understand how to capture the *args and **kwargs in f then this would shed some light on the subject.

Comment: Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23115105/1903116) to understand the basics of how decorators work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper function is necessary, and a standard part of how decorator definitions in Python work.

You can, however, help mask the existence of the wrapper function in tracebacks by using `functools.wraps()`:

```
import functools

def f(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This will update the wrapper function to have the name and docstring of the wrapped function.

--

Decorators are nothing more than functions which are passed a function. This code...

```
def dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@dec
def myfunc(foo, bar):
    return foo+bar
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
def dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def myfunc(foo, bar):
    return foo+bar

myfunc = dec(myfunc)
```

Notice how the thing being passed to `dec` is a *function* which hasn't even been called yet - so there aren't any arguments passed at the time when `dec` is invoked. This is why the wrapper function is involved: it adds a layer which will be called *when the original function is invoked* which can capture arguments.

Comment: That was where I misunderstood, I thought that func was called through dec(func).  My next question is:  Why does def wrapper() call func?

Comment: Because there's a call to `func` in the `wrapper`...?

Comment: @Robert because the name `myfunc` is getting overwritten to point to the wrapper function provided by your decorator, and thus in order to have the original functionality for `myfunc` (in addition to whatever you want your decorator to do) you have to also call the original function (which is what `func` is).